# ios ShareKit 2.0 method for getting user friends list from facebook?

Tags: ios, facebook, list, friend, sharekit

Is there a method in ShareKit 2.0 ios sdk that returns the loged in user (facebook) friends?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not. But you can subclass SHKFacebook and request it from Facebook, as far as it is possible to get this information through Graph API

Comment: I made a method to return what i needed. Thanks

Comment: Can you share the method please?

Comment: @vilem kurz  one of my clients has requested to add feature to share images to a facebook friend via message. How can we do that?